# Update balloon position as element moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using [jquery.balloon.js](http://urin.github.io/jquery.balloon.js/#cite_note-0) for validation error message display, it's working good but I want it to stay with my control when it moves as I have some divs hide/show because of which position of control changes and balloon's position messes up.

**Correct Position :)**

[image]

Some hidden div shows and changes control's position.

**Incorrect Position :(**

[image]

Comment: Build a fiddle with your code, please. Right now, we cannot tell you anything. If all goes well, though, there is a CSS fix possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `offsetX, offsetY` options in the plugin. For an example

`$('.sample3').balloon({ offsetX: -20, offsetY: -10 });`

Calculate the position of the element prior to the showing of the balloon and then add the values to the init function.